# Sorting an ArrayList<Object> works only with newer smartphones

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have to sort my ArrayList through a value of my Object. Its the distance value i calculate before. This works perfectly but if i try to sort it ascending, the older smartphones show different values than the actual distance is but the distance is calculated right. I think its because of my sort method. So how can i sort this arraylist no matter which operating system is currently installed. Here is my Object:

```
public class SellerObject implements Serializable {

private String imageUrl, lat, lng, name, plz, id, size, price, typ, url;
private Float distance;


public SellerObject(String imageUrl, String lat, String lng, String name, String plz, String id, String size, String price, String typ, String url, Float distance) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.name = name;
    this.plz = plz;
    this.id = id;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
    this.typ = typ;
    this.url = url;
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getTyp() {
    return typ;
}

public void setTyp(String typ) {
    this.typ = typ;
}

public SellerObject() {
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(String lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPlz() {
    return plz;
}

public void setPlz(String plz) {
    this.plz = plz;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Float getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Float distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}


public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

}

and here is my Sort method:

```
  private void SortUser(ArrayList<SellerObject> newSeller) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        newSeller.sort(Comparator.comparing(SellerObject::getDistance));

    }
    loadingview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    sellerAdapter sa = new sellerAdapter(getActivity(), newSeller, mlastLocation);
    sellerrv.setAdapter(sa);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You AllarList is not getting sorted in phones with old os as you use it only if Android os is Nougat or newer, and you have to do that as sort function in the ArrayList required API 24 or later, so to fix tour issue, you have to handle older versions also, and Collections.sort will be a perfect solution for you.

Hence, the whole sort functionality will be like that:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   newSeller.sort(Comparator.comparing(SellerObject::getDistance));
}else{
    Collections.sort(newSeller, new Comparator<SellerObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SellerObject item1, SellerObject item2) {
            return item1.getDistance.compareTo(item2.getDistance);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are sorting the `List<SellerObject>` only if the Android version in use is *Nougat* or newer.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   newSeller.sort(Comparator.comparing(SellerObject::getDistance));
}
```